# Non blocking python class method executed with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to initialize a non-blocking task, which shares data with its parent object. It is a websocket client, and it would not block the main execution, though still run "forever".

My humble expectations were this would do it, but sadly, it is blocking the main thread.

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(self.initWS())
loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.initWS()` is indeed not blocking the main thread, but `loop.run_forever()` is.

If you want to execute more tasks concurrently with `self.initWS()`, you have to add them to the asyncio loop, too.